# Having trouble converting a string of number separated by spaces into an int array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm trying to do the Euler problem 6 put where the user inputs what numbers they want the sum square difference of. The programs dies the moment I run it and I get the feeling its because of the conversion from the input string into the array that I use to actually do the math. I've looked all over google and haven't been able to find anything that made sense to me to fix it with. I just started programming so a lot of the fixes go over my head for converting a string into an int array.

**EDIT: and by dies I mean the app crashes the moment i ask it to solve with the "Unfortunate project Euler has stopped" error message when i try any input.**

Here's my code:

```
public String solve(String input) {
    try {
        StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input);
        int count = strToken.countTokens();
        int[] arr = new int[count];
        for(int x = 0;x < count;x++){
            arr[x] = Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());
        }
        return String.valueOf(solve(arr));
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return "Please only enter an integer";
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }

}

private int solve(int[] number){
    int sumSquared=0;
    int squaredSum=0;
    int i;
    int answer;

    for(i=0;i<=number.length;i++){
        sumSquared=number[i]+sumSquared;
    }
    for(i=0;i<number.length;i++){
        squaredSum= (int) (Math.pow(number[i],2)+squaredSum);
    }
    sumSquared= (int) Math.pow(sumSquared,2);
    answer=sumSquared+squaredSum;

    return answer ;
}
```

}

Comment: Please elaborate on "dies." I assume an exception is thrown? What is it and at what source line?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dies"? Is there an exception? What gets returned (if anything)? What input are you providing?

Comment: It could be an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the line `for(i=0;i<=number.length;i++)` ... change the condition to `i < number.length`.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but please post the **exact** exception text, and **where** this exception is being thrown in your code. You can get this by running your program in a debugger. This will save people from having to read and mentally compile your entire sample (or pasting it into an IDE and running it themselves).

Comment: Why are you using StringTokenizer? What is the expected input to solve? How are you running this, that you are getting that error message? If there is an exception being thrown, you should be able to see what it is.

Comment: @dvnrrs They can't run it themselves, since it isn't a complete program, and it is unclear what form the input will take.

Comment: Also, problem 6 requires you to compute the difference, not the sum (see the line where you are returning `answer`).

Comment: Thank you  Chthonic Project. It would appear that that was exactly what the problem was and I noticed the fact that i had a plus and not a minus when i went back to fix that "=". =D

Thank you everyone for help. Sorry I made it so confusing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since it seems that you are unable to obtain the exact exception, I just ran your code, and here's why it fails:

```
for(i=0;i<=number.length;i++){
    sumSquared=number[i]+sumSquared;
}
```

This throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception. Once I corrected this to

```
for(i=0;i< number.length;i++){
    sumSquared=number[i]+sumSquared;
}
```

the code ran fine.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, whenever you have a code, always test it using your own `main(String[])` method. This is especially useful when your code is going to be integrated into someone else's code.